# Rename "interactive-broker" tag to "interactive-brokers"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

It appears that "Interactive Broker" is a misspelling. It is supposed to be "Interactive Broker**s**" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Brokers).

[interactive-broker](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interactive-broker) should be renamed to [interactive-brokers](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interactive-brokers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done - I didn't bother creating a synonym, but I can do if the "wrong" one creeps back.

Comment: How did you do it? Are moderators able to rename tags without first creating a synonym?

Comment: @Flux I merged it with the new tag name (even though that didn't actually exist). I assume that's mod-only functionality as it seems a bit dangerous to be freely available :-)